# Unable to Install blender in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dependencies

I'm new to Ubuntu and when ever I try to update or install `blender`, I encounter this error in the terminal.

This is the error that pops up:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSssk.png]

Could someone tell me what exactly to do?

I have used the following code as suggested in blender website,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thomas-schiex/blender  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install blender
```

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text. Copy & paste the text from terminal with Ctrl+Alt+C for copying and Ctrl+V for pasting here. Thank you.

Comment: Also show us the command you used.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to add any repository; simply run

```
sudo apt install blender
```

It's available by default, you don't need thomas-shiex repo.

Or alternatively you can do

```
sudo snap install blender --classic
```

Comment: If you have added it now, remove the repository from "ubuntu software and updates" application